# Rails 4 I18n : New translation not working and missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm currently facing a really weird issue. Translating my app, I've created some defaults key inside `config/locales/en.yml` :

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  default:
    country: "Your country is %{name}"
    ...
```

Everything works fine so far. However, now I'm adding a new key inside the same file (and saving that file of course) :

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  default:
    country: "Your country is %{name}"
    group: "Group with name %{name}"
    ...
```

and I'm calling it like :

```
# app/views/home/index.html.haml
= t('default.group', name: "Test name")
```

However, it's always returning me "Translation missing...". When using an old key (e,g, en.country) :

```
# app/views/home/index.html.haml
= t('default.country', name: "US")
```

It's working.

This is a weird behavior and cannot find why this is not working. Any new keys that I'm adding dont seems to be found.

Ideas?

**EDIT :**
Realized the problem happened only when I'm using it with `render_to_string` method :

```
# app/views/home/partial.html.haml
= t('default.group', name: "Group name")

# controller
def action
  render_to_string(
    template: "path/to/partial"
  )
end
```

But if the view is :

```
# app/views/home/_partial.html.haml
= t('default.country', name: "US")
```

It works.

**EDIT 2 :**
Ok I know why it's not working. I'm actually using Sidekiq under the hood to in my pub/sub system for notify users.
Since the worker is executed in its own context, I have to manually include the right class/helper. However, do you have any idea which class/helper?

For example, in order to use `route` helper, I'm doing :

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

so what to use to load I18n?

Comment: Did you restart  the server?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Yes I did restart the server. But it's not working

Comment: Sure you yaml is valid ? check it here https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: Yep, just checked and the yaml is ok

Comment: i guess you have import task to the YAML file after you imported it doesn't make any change if you change it in the YAML file, you need to override the records to get it updated.

Comment: I think it would be better to start a new question rather than edit and change completely the focus of the initial question.

Comment: Here is the moved topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734842/rails-4-sidekiq-does-not-recognize-the-i18n-helper

Answer (score 3):

Looks good. Make sure you restart your server as YML changes are not loaded dynamically.

If the problem persists, try it out in console. Translate something to initialize the I18n backend, e.g. with:

```
I18n.t(:whatever)
```

and then inspect the `translations` hash:

```
I18n.backend.send(:translations)
```

Do you see your new keys there? Are you sure you are on the English, `:en`, locale?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The translation are all present. I realized that the problem comes from when I'm using `t(:key)` from `render_to_string` method

Comment: Console is your friend :) Helps isolate the cause faster

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer as I know now why it's not working. But I still need some help